# SCSS adding argument to content directive

Tags: sass, scss-mixins

I created mixin to change the theme colors and it's good but I need to improve it, here it's:

```
@mixin themes($rule, $key) {
    $themes: (
        default: (
            color-primary: $c24-color-primary,
            color-primary-light: $c24-color-primary-light,
            color-primary-lighter2: lighten($c24-color-primary-light, 2%),
            color-primary-lighter20: lighten($c24-color-primary-light, 20%)
        ),
        blackFriday: (
            color-primary: $c24-color-lvl10-black,
            color-primary-light: $c24-color-darkest-grey,
            color-primary-lighter2: lighten($c24-color-darkest-grey, 2%),
            color-primary-lighter20: lighten($c24-color-darkest-grey, 20%)
        )
    );

    @each $label, $maps in $themes {
        @if $label == default {
            #{$rule}: map-get($maps, $key);
        } @else {
            body.#{$label} & {
                #{$rule}: map-get($maps, $key);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What I need to do is to add multiple rules not only one how to do that ?

Comment: Can you give an example of how you would want to pass the rules to the mixin?

Comment: This is only for one rule @include themes('background-color', 'color-primary');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can send a [map](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/values/maps) of your rules to the `@mixin` and loop over it :

```
@mixin themes($rules, $key) {
    [...]

    @each $label, $maps in $themes {
        @if $label == default {
            @each $rule in $rules {
                #{$rule}: map-get($maps, $key);
            }
        } @else {
            body.#{$label} & {
                @each $rule in $rules {
                    #{$rule}: map-get($maps, $key);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can then call your `@mixin` as:

```
@include themes((background-color, color), 'color-primary');
```

Or with a variable containing the rules:

```
$rules: background-color, color;
@include themes($rules, 'color-primary');
```

In case you would want to use the [spreading operator](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/mixin#taking-arbitrary-arguments), you will need to reverse the parameters in the `@mixin`:

```
@mixin themes($key, $rules...) { [...] }
@include themes('color-primary', background-color, color);
```